# Evalution of a function where $t = x + \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: inequality, quadratics, substitution

Consider a function $$y=(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3})-6(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})+3(x+\frac{1}{x})$$ defined for real $x>0$. Letting $t=x+\frac{1}{x}$ gives: $$y=t^3-6t^2+12$$

Here it holds that $$t=x+\frac{1}{x}\geq2$$

My question is: how do  I know that $t=x+\frac{1}{x}\geq2$  ?
I want to know how to get to this point without previouly knowing that $t=x+\frac{1}{x}\geq2$

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for not noticing it. Do you have any tips about how I can see that the AM GM method can be used?

Comment: If the product of the terms is 'nicer' than the sum, then it may be worth applying AM-GM.  There are a ton of [classical inequalities](https://brilliant.org/wiki/classical-inequalities/) which are useful only in specific situations, so in general, it just comes down to practice. There are also methods using calculus, which I assume you are familiar with based on your other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because by AM-GM $$x+\frac{1}{x}\geq2\sqrt{x\cdot\frac{1}{x}}=2.$$
Your calculation of $y$ is right:
$$y=t^3-3t-6(t^2-2)+3t=t^3-6t^2+12$$ and you got it without using $t\geq2$.

Comment: Any tips on how to notice this method can be used?

Comment: @Renato What do you want to get? Do you want to prove something?

Comment: If I did not previously know this identity, is there some hint to notice AM-GM can be used?

Comment: @Renato For the proof that $y=t^3-6t^2+12$ we don't need it.

Answer (score 3):

We have that for $x>0$

$$x+\frac{1}{x}\geq2 \iff x\cdot x+x\cdot \frac{1}{x}\geq x\cdot 2 \iff x^2-2x+1\ge 0 \iff (x-1)^2 \ge 0$$

and the equality holds if and only if $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

hint: use AM GM inequality ,a+b/2 is greater than or equal to root(ab) for positive a,b

Comment: Any tips on how to notice this method can be used?

Comment: @Renato Mostly ,if the terms are given to be positive and we can write them in such a way that their GM is a constant number then we can use it.